# How do one count how many text values contain in row in powerquery

Tags: excel, powerquery

Good day all,Excel has a function called ISTEXT

So,if intend to get all the text containing in a record,
I will use =SUM(..ISTEXT(B1:B4))
If my data range is B1:B4.
As shown i below:

| B1 | B2 | B4 | count of text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1003 | A2 | A1 | 2 |
| 1010 | D | D | 2 |
| 1004 | A2 | 2 | 1 |
| 1007 | B2 | B4 | 2 |
| 1009 |  |  | 0 |
| 1003 | A2 | A1 | 2 |
| BCD | C |  | 2 |
| 1004 | A2 | 2 | 1 |

The challenge is how do I achieve this using powerquery.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umut has the right idea

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Count = Table.AddColumn(Source, "count of text", each List.Sum(List.Transform(List.RemoveNulls(Record.FieldValues(_)),each if Value.Is(_,type number) then 0 else 1)))
in Count
```

Comment: i may have the right idea but not enough skills to write such a code )))

Answer (score -1):

you can use [Value.Is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/value-is)

sample

```
if Value.Is([data],type number) 
then "Number"
else "Text"
```

you can use as below but if you have more "B" columns, then you should use a custom function...

```
let
        Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
        #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Count Texts", each (if Value.Is([B1], type text) then 1 else 0 ) +
    (if Value.Is([B2], type text) then 1 else 0 )+
    (if Value.Is([B4], type text) then 1 else 0 ))
    in
        #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: ,so if I have 21 number of columns or more  ,I will have to repeat  the formular for each cells?

Comment: @val if you share more sample data and expected result, we can be more helpful...

Comment: kindly make use of the edited data shared above.                                                                   Thank you.

Comment: @val you didnt mention clearly that you want to count the data containing text. is this the case ?

Comment: Yes, i want to count data containing text, using powerquery

Comment: @horseyride is a great M coder , he'll find a way to count with all dynamic B columns...